# HTTP405: BAD METHOD - (XHR)Put :: Only on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Background: Using Angular, .net Core 2.2. Using windows authentication.

I am getting "HTTP405: Bad Method - The HTTP verb used is not supported" on the server (works fine locally) when trying to make any put request on the server. Does anyone know why? I can't seem to find the issue as I am declaring the request as a HttpPut at the controller level, is there some configuration I have to set up on IIS?

I have my web api controller set up as:

```
namespace appSchool.APIs
{
[Authorize]
[Route("api/engagements")]
public class EngagementController : ControllerBase
{

    EngagementProvider _engagementProvider;
    ILogger _logger;

    public EngagementController(EngagementProvider engagementProvider, ILogger<EngagementController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _engagementProvider = engagementProvider;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var engs = await _engagementProvider.GetEngagementsAsync();
            var dtoEngs = Engagement.MapForDto(engs);
            return Ok(dtoEngs);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exp.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, exp);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody]Engagement eng)
    {
        try
        {
            var newEng = await _engagementProvider.InsertEngagementAsync(eng);
            if (newEng == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Unable to insert engagement");
            }
            return Ok(newEng);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exp.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, exp);
        }
    }
    [HttpPut]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Put([FromBody]Engagement eng)
    {
        try
        {
            var updEng = await _engagementProvider.UpdateEngagementAsync(eng);
            if (updEng == null)
            {
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
            return Ok(updEng);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exp.Message);
            return StatusCode(500, exp);
        }
    }
```

And my request in angular service is

```
updateEngagement(updatedEngagement: Engagement) : Observable<Engagement> {
    return this.http.put<Engagement>(this.engagementUrl, updatedEngagement);
}
```

Comment: Do you have WebDAV module installed on your IIS? You can perform failed request tracing on IIS, if you have access to your server. See here to understand how to do that - https://stackify.com/beyond-iis-logs-find-failed-iis-asp-net-requests/

Comment: Why are you getting a 405 when your code is returning a 500?  It appears it is not getting to your code.  Did code every work?  If so when was last time it worked?   Does it work with other Post.

Comment: @jdweng - 405 is a client error and means that the endpoint itself has not been hit. You will get a 500 only when there is actual execution happening at the endpoint and the processing in the endpoint has erred.

Comment: Exactly, it does not hit the server or the 500. It instead fails before and gives 405 bad method.

Comment: Put does work fine locally and post/get works fine on the server. It does not work at all on the server for put methods

Comment: The you are making a good connection if the GET is working.  Are you using same service (and version) locally and remotely?

Comment: @jdweng Same service and everything. It is every put request fails 405 bad method when on the server.

Comment: Then is probably a permission issue.  A client connecting to a IIS has GUEST privileges and client have very little access to the machine resources like the file system.  A quick test is to run service on IIS as Admin and see if you still have a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. IIS disables PUT requests on the server by default. I had to make modifications to the web config to allow put requests to come in.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <remove name="aspNetCore" />
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```